# how to use hadoop for a web application?

Tags: hadoop

I am working on a social networking web based application, which is uses Apache web server and MYSQL server for database with codeigniter MVC frameworks. I don't know how to integrate Hadoop in this application and how to write map- reduce program.

Answer (score 14):

Hadoop and map-reduce have no direct relationship to web applications. You should not integrate Hadoop into a web application as long as you understand web application as something that responds (quickly) to user input (web requests).

Hadoop and map-reduce are very useful for algorithms that run on large datasets in order to transform/extract data/knowledge from those datasets.

Comment: thanks for response, I come to know that Hadoop is not for realtime application. It is useful for offline processing. Hbase is for dynamic read and write at realtime. so write now learning Hbase.

Comment: My understanding is that Spark does have realtime capabilities, and is often able to stand in for MapReduce.  What's time revealed to you, @Rashmi?

Answer (score 9):

While it is true that Hadoop is nowadays mostly used for "offline analytics", it can be useful to web projects as well. For example, to pre-compute recommendations or suggestions that are then provided to the users of a website.

Another case of use is to be able to ETL from multiple sources of data to produce an inverted index for a website (for example, jobs/cars/rentals-like websites with huge amounts of input data).

Always think of Hadoop when you have a "Big Data" problem, not if your website is managing small amounts of data.

Using Hadoop to tackle this sort of problems has some advantages and disadvantages. The obvious advantage is that it makes any sort of batch process (like the examples I mentioned) scale transparently. The disadvantage is that it isn't real-time: you can't use Hadoop to update your website every 5 seconds.

Comment: The question was "How to use Hadoop...".

Comment: Also, I do not understand how your examples contrast "offline analytics". What you describe is still offline processing.

Answer (score 3):

I think Hadoop can have two "classic" usages for the social network style of applications.

First is usage of HBASE to store messaging and other dynamic information. Storage of user profiles in the HBASE also can be considered in order to completely replace MySQL with this kind of NoSQL solution.

Second is usage of Hadoop MapReduce for analysis of Your network. Good example of such analysis is looking for friends suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I am configured Hbase in standalone mode. How to use this mode for any application. I know Java. My website is based on codeigniter and php. any help on this. thanks

Comment: HBase standalone mode can be used as usual but it should not be used to evaluate performance, because HDFS is not involved. What problem are you trying to solve with HBase?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes it is possible to make web application using apache hadoop as a back-end**

You can create web application using apache hive and pig  you can write custom mapper and reducers and use as udf , but personal experience it is slow , In case you have very less data , It is better to use other database and do analytics. ,  I prefer spark is the solution for better reponse time..

Comment: How this could be done directly ?- Since there is no direct way to connect a web app with Hadoop ? Can you provide any reference site for this @shubham

Answer (score 1):

By using hadoop analyse your data and take the results into your mysql database. Then use that with your web application.

Answer (score 0):

In your web application you can get required data from Hadoop (like job results) using REST services: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/WebServicesIntro.html